# A page can have only one server-side Form tag.(how can i add multiple forms in master page)

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Hi i am using form in my master page as i want to show a dropdown menu from database table here is my code

```
<body>
      <form id="form1"  runat="server">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="navbar-brand logo">
                         <a href="home.aspx"><span>Ads</span>Valley</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownCity" CssClass="DropDownCity" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownCountry" CssClass="DropDownCity">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownCate" CssClass="DropDownCity">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                      <asp:HyperLink ID="Pending" NavigateUrl="~/Requests.aspx" runat="server" CssClass="PendingReq">Pending Request<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Spam" CssClass="badge"></asp:Label></asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="ButtonLogout" runat="server" CssClass="Adminlogout" NavigateUrl="~/Logout.aspx">Logout</asp:HyperLink> 
                </div  
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="main-banner banner text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Sell <span class="segment-heading">Anything Online For Free </span>With AdsValley</h1>
            <h3><strong><span class="auto-style2">Welcome Admin</span></strong></h3>
            <p>
                &nbsp;</p>

        </div>
    </div>
           </form>       
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>   
</body>
</html>
```

and now i want to use another form in child page as i want to  show data on my page from database table using grid view but i am facing this error
"A page can have only one server-side Form tag." what could be the possible solution can you please guide me?
here is child page // requests.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin_MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Requests.aspx.cs" Inherits="Requests" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AdsId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cat_ID" HeaderText="Category ID" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ad_Title" HeaderText="Ads Title" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Brand" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Conditions" HeaderText="Conditions" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageName" HeaderText="Image Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageContent" HeaderText="Image Content" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Photo1" HeaderText="Photo 1" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Photo2" HeaderText="Photo 2" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Photo3" HeaderText="Photo 3" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true"
                ItemStyle-Width="100" />
       <asp:CommandField  ButtonType="Link" EditText="Accept" ShowEditButton="true"/>
        </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconnection %>"
          SelectCommand="SELECT [Country], [Cat_ID], [Ad_Title], [Brand], [Model], [Price], [Description], [Owner], [ImageName], [ImageContent], [Photo1], [Contact], [City], [Date], [Owner_ID], [Conditions], [Photo2], [Photo3] FROM [Ads]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE Ads SET Country = @Country, Cat_ID = @catId, Ad_Title=@tite, Brand=@brand, Model=@mod, Price=@prc, Description=@des, Conditions=@cond, Owner=@own, Contact=@cont, City=@City, Date=@d, ImageName=@imgn, ImageContent=@imgCot, Photo1=@ph1, Photo2=@ph2, Photo3=@ph3 WHERE AdsId = @AdsId"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Country WHERE AdsId = @AdsId">
       <%-- define paramerters here--%>
         <UpdateParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="AdsId" Type="Int32" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter  Name="catId" Type="Int32"/>
             <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="brand" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="mod" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="prc" Type="Int32" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="des" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="cond" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="own" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="cont" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="city" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="d" Type="DateTime" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="imgn" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="imgCot" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="ph1" Type="String"/>
             <asp:Parameter Name="ph2" Type="String"/>
             <asp:Parameter Name="ph3" Type="String"/>
         </UpdateParameters>
         <DeleteParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="AdsId" Type="Int32" />
         </DeleteParameters>
     </asp:SqlDataSource>   
 </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Remove your `<form>` tag from your Content page. Then read about how asp.net handles forms: https://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: You can't really have multiple forms in Web Forms. You can, but only one of them can be marked as `runat="server"` and of course they can't be nested in each other. If this is an issue for you, then Web Forms is not the correct solution for you and you should check out [ASP.NET MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc) or a new client side framework (Angular or React etc) talking to a [Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api) backend. In fact, you should be looking to move off Web Forms anyways.